# Is there a way to make one integer increase when a second integer increases by a set amount in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple game in python 3 and I'm trying to build in an EXP system, for example, every 50 experience points, your health (Which is already an integer) increases by one. Is there a command for this?

(I'm coding this on repl.it if that matters)

Comment: Much too vague. This site is for much more specific questions. Try game-programming tutorials?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've never shunned guessing. :)

Let me suppose that you are incrementing a variable called `experience_points` and that, once for every 50 times you increment that you want to increment a variable called `health` by one.

```
experience_points += 1
if experience_points % 50 == 0:
    health +=1
```

This bit of code shows how this might work. Notice how `health` goes up one for every 50 times that 'experience_points` goes up one.

Welcome to the modulus operator!

```
>>> experience_points = 0
>>> health = 0
>>> while True:
...     # do something in the game
...     experience_points += 1
...     if experience_points % 50 == 0:
...         health += 1
...     print (experience_points, health, '<--', end='')
...     if experience_points > 160:
...         break
...     
1 0 <--2 0 <--3 0 <--4 0 <--5 0 <--6 0 <--7 0 <--8 0 <--9 0 <--10 0 <--11 0 <--12 0 <--13 0 <--14 0 <--15 0 <--16 0 <--17 0 <--18 0 <--19 0 <--20 0 <--21 0 <--22 0 <--23 0 <--24 0 <--25 0 <--26 0 <--27 0 <--28 0 <--29 0 <--30 0 <--31 0 <--32 0 <--33 0 <--34 0 <--35 0 <--36 0 <--37 0 <--38 0 <--39 0 <--40 0 <--41 0 <--42 0 <--43 0 <--44 0 <--45 0 <--46 0 <--47 0 <--48 0 <--49 0 <--50 1 <--51 1 <--52 1 <--53 1 <--54 1 <--55 1 <--56 1 <--57 1 <--58 1 <--59 1 <--60 1 <--61 1 <--62 1 <--63 1 <--64 1 <--65 1 <--66 1 <--67 1 <--68 1 <--69 1 <--70 1 <--71 1 <--72 1 <--73 1 <--74 1 <--75 1 <--76 1 <--77 1 <--78 1 <--79 1 <--80 1 <--81 1 <--82 1 <--83 1 <--84 1 <--85 1 <--86 1 <--87 1 <--88 1 <--89 1 <--90 1 <--91 1 <--92 1 <--93 1 <--94 1 <--95 1 <--96 1 <--97 1 <--98 1 <--99 1 <--100 2 <--101 2 <--102 2 <--103 2 <--104 2 <--105 2 <--106 2 <--107 2 <--108 2 <--109 2 <--110 2 <--111 2 <--112 2 <--113 2 <--114 2 <--115 2 <--116 2 <--117 2 <--118 2 <--119 2 <--120 2 <--121 2 <--122 2 <--123 2 <--124 2 <--125 2 <--126 2 <--127 2 <--128 2 <--129 2 <--130 2 <--131 2 <--132 2 <--133 2 <--134 2 <--135 2 <--136 2 <--137 2 <--138 2 <--139 2 <--140 2 <--141 2 <--142 2 <--143 2 <--144 2 <--145 2 <--146 2 <--147 2 <--148 2 <--149 2 <--150 3 <--151 3 <--152 3 <--153 3 <--154 3 <--155 3 <--156 3 <--157 3 <--158 3 <--159 3 <--160 3 <--161 3 <--
```